# Why is the output of this program -1?

Tags: java

I'm studying for my final exam in AP Computer Science and I came across this question:

```
int sum = 0, p = 1;
for (int count = 1; count <= 50; count++)
{
    sum += p;
    p *= 2;
}
```

The output is -1; however I don't understand why that is the case. If someone can explain it to me that would be awesome.

Comment: [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

Answer (score 6):

By adding 1,2,4,8,..., You basically fill the binary representation of `sum` with 1's.

Since `111..1` is the representation of `-1`, you actually generate this number.

This is often regarded as [Integer Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the previous answer(s).

An integer in java is represented by [32 bits](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). Thus, it is easy to see that the max value that can be represented with an int is:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111  1111 1111 1111 1111 (which is 32 1's)
```

And this value equates to:

```
(1)*2^0 + (1)*2^1 + (1)*2^2 + ... + (1)*2^31 = 2^32 - 1 = 4294967295
```

But then how do ints represent negative numbers?

The answer is that the above calculation and limit only apply to unsigned values that are represented using 32 bits.

Negative numbers are represented using the [Sign Bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_bit) which corresponds to the left-most bit or [MSB or Most Significant Bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit).

- If Sign Bit = 1, as in 110, the number is negative
- and vice versa

Also, due to the fact that signed numbers require a bit to be set aside for keeping track of the sign, signed numbers will never be able to represent numbers larger than unsigned numbers, simply because they have less bits.

Knowing that the MSB is simply the sign bit for signed values, how do we find out what the actual number is?

The answer is to use [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). According to Wikipedia, Two's Complement is simply a way to ensure that:

> "...positive and negative numbers can coexist in a natural way."

Two's Complement can convert a positive signed integer X, that has sign bit = 0, into negative -X.

For example (Using 8 bits):

```
0110 1001 is the 2^0 + 2^3 + 2^5 + 2^6 = 105
```

To get the representation of -105, we use Two's Complement, which is done by:

1. Flipping all bits, so 0 -> 1 and 1 -> 0
2. Adding one to the result

So in our example, -105 would be represented by:

1. Flipping all bits, so 0 -> 1 and 1 -> 0

   ```
   0110 1001 -> 1001 0110
   ```
2. Adding one to the result.

   ```
   1001 0110 + 0000 0001 = 1001 0111
   ```

Thus we get `1001 0111` as our representation of -105

So how does all this relate the question?

The reason that the program is outputting a -1 is because the int is a signed number variable. As the previous answer mentioned, the program is stuffing the 32 bits allocated for the int sum with 1's.

You can see this nicely if you put in print statement, like this `System.out.print(sum + ", ");` printing out the value of sum as the loop goes on, what you end up seeing is something like this:

```
1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127, 255, 511, 1023, 2047, 4095, 8191, 16383, 32767, 65535, 131071, 262143, 524287, 1048575, 2097151, 4194303, 8388607, 16777215, 33554431, 67108863, 134217727, 268435455, 536870911, 1073741823, 2147483647, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
```

Which in binary is:

```
1, 11, 111, 1111, 1 1111, ....
```

And if you add an if statement to catch the value of count when sum goes to -1, you find that it goes to -1 right when count = 32. Which makes sense, given the fact that once you the program stuffs a 1 in the MSB or Sign Bit, the 32 bit number is treated as a negative number.

Now using Two's Complement we can find out exactly what that negative number is by exploiting the fact that not only can you get the negative representation of a number, but you can also get the positive representation, if you are given a negative number. Thus, we have:

1. Flipping all bits, so 0 -> 1 and 1 -> 0

   ```
   1111 1111 1111 1111  1111 1111 1111 1111 -> 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
   ```
2. Adding one to the result.

   ```
   0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 + 0001 = 0001
   ```

Which represents the number 1. Thus, we find that `1111 1111 1111 1111  1111 1111 1111 1111` is the representation for -1.